# Why does my gas water heater have two pairs of water connections?

Tags: plumbing

Why does my gas water heater have hot and cold water connections on the top of the tank and another set on the side of the tank?

Comment: What model? So that we could look up the manual or pictures.

Comment: Are the pipes on the side connected to a boiler? Could you include the make and model, and some photos?

Answer (score 1):

1 set of connections for the sinks and one set for a water-based central heating system.

These systems are kept separated because the pipes and radiators used in such a central heating system is not meant for containing drinking water. (If you ever bled such a system you'd know from the smell alone)

Answer (score -1):

The second set should be for your heating, whether radiant or forced air.